# Chainlink `@` syntax or Github url?

Tags: chainlink

I'm going over Chainlink tutorials.

Sometime I see Chainlink imports using `@chainlink/path/to/contract` and other times `https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/path/to/contract`.

Are Contracts in production suppose to use the live Github link? Or the other import?

I'm confused, because I can't find any explanation for when you'd want to use one vs the other.

When do you use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first import with `@` is for a local import and the second one is for an online version.

What you typically do in projects is install a node package locally and use that (the first version). The benefit is that the package will never change, it's always available (no need to worry about possible connectivity issues) and is faster to use.

If you use an online version you have to have connectivity and there are no guarantees that the package wouldn't change (yes, even if the URI has a version number the package can, in theory, change). This kind of import is typically only used for quick testing and prototyping - it shouldn't be used in production.